# Anytime my node server starts an error displays after it has started

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

here's the error it displays

```
(node:2134) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/Users/danieldx/Documents/Yelpapp/V2/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:826:32)
    at Mongoose.connect (/Users/danieldx/Documents/Yelpapp/V2/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:335:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/danieldx/Documents/Yelpapp/V2/app.js:6:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1196:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:929:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:2134) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2134) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Are you sure your mongod process is running?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node js Error: Mongoose with MondoDB connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61150387/node-js-error-mongoose-with-mondodb-connection-string)

Comment: @thammada.ts no it was not running but it is now, thanks it's solved now.